# Alternate between add and subtract on a list

Tags: python

Does anybody here know how to sum elements from a list alternating the sign? I tried this:

```
i = 40
suma = 0
sign = 1

while i <= 100:
    suma = suma + sign * i
    sign = sign * -1
    i = i + 1
    
print(suma)
```

but I don't know how to improve it into a function and add a list. Please help.

Comment: what is the problem to put it in `def` and use `for number in list`

Answer (score 4):

```
def add_alternate_sign(a_list):
    total = 0
    for i, number in enumerate(a_list):
        total += number * (-1) ** i

    print(total)


numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
add_alternate_sign(numbers)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy` for faster vectorized operation. Using your example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1, 101)
np.sum(x*(-1)**x)
```

For any arbitrary list:

```
x = [5,10,20,100,2, 1]
y = np.array(x)
np.sum(y*(-1)**np.arange(len(x)))
```

Comment: I just provide a code for his example, in his example, he is summing over 1:100

Comment: I added another case for arbitrary list

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.cycle` to loop continuously through `1, -1` for the multiplier. For example:

```
import itertools

def alternate_sum(a):
    """
    sums elements of a list with alternating multiplier +1, -1, +1, -1, ...
    """
    return sum(x * s for x, s in zip(a, itertools.cycle([1, -1])))

print(alternate_sum([10,11,12,14,15]))
```

This approach is not limited to special case of +1 and -1; it could be used for any sequence of multipliers (of any length).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
def alternate_sum(a):
    """
    return sum of the elements of a with alternating multiplier 1, -1, ... 
    """
    return sum(x * (-1)**i for i, x in enumerate(a))
```

Here `i` is the index number 0, 1, 2, ...., so `(-1)**i` is the sequence 1, -1, 1, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use slices to sum alternate entries in a list:

```
def altsum(v):
    return sum(v[0::2]) - sum(v[1::2])
```

The only downside is that the slice creates two new lists, one with the even indexes and the other with the odd indexes. If your original list is big, that's a lot of wasted storage (and some time).

So you could use `itertools.islice` to avoid creating the lists, although it's unlikely to turn out to be faster since `islice` is not optimised for lists, as far as I know.

```
from itertools import islice
def altsum(v):
    return sum(islice(v, 0, None, 2)) - sum(islice(v, 1, None, 2))
```

But that won't work for arbitrary iterables because it relies on being able to iterate the argument twice. To construct the alternating sum of an arbitrary iterable, you can use `itertools.zip_longest` (or `itertools.izip_longest` in Python 2) along with `functools.reduce` (or `reduce` in Python 2):

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import zip_longest

def altsum(v):
    it = iter(v)
    return reduce(lambda accum, pn: accum + pn[0] - pn[1],
                  zip_longest(it, it, fillvalue=0), 0)
```